# How to Get friend list from Facebook SDK 3.0

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I am new in Facebook integration with android. I've logged in to Facebook by using facebook-android-SDK-3.0.
(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/)

Now I want to get all friends name, birthday and display in ListView, and Click on list Post on friends' wall.

http://img829.imageshack.us/img829/6136/samplefriendslistbirthd.jpg

How can I do this?

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Lets check out the FriendPickerSample in Facebook-SDK3.0